# How can you pass data from a UIContainerView to an other UIContainerView, which are in the same parent viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uicontainerview

I'm struggling to get my data from a `UIContainerView` to another `UIContainerView`. For example: I have 2 containers, which are `calculatorContainer` and `displayResultContainer`. So when I press "=" button to calculate the result, I want it to show up in the `displayResultContainer`. I already tried different options with the segue method and `parentViewController` access, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities.
1.Using appDelegate. Use a property in app delegate to pass data between containers.
Put this in first container

```
 MyAppdeleagte appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; 
   appDelegate.dataToPass=dataToPass;
```

in the second container

```
MyAppdeleagte appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; 
   dataToPass=appDelegate.dataToPass;
```

2.Using ParentViewController.

in first container

```
 ParentViewController parent=(ParentViewController *)[self parentViewController];
                      parent.dataToPass=dataToPass;
```

in the second container

```
 ParentViewController parent=(ParentViewController *)[self parentViewController];
data=parent.dataToPass;
```

Comment: The AppDelegate method worked for me, pretty straightforward. I was making it too difficult for myself! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use delegates.

Steps:

1. From 1st UIContainerView, call a delegate method to the parent view controller.
2. The parentview controller then pass the value to the 2nd UIContainerView.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy method, but first you should know that this method works for forward flow not backward (in backward flow you will need a thing called delegate):

```
View 1 = calculator
View 2 = result display.
```

In view2 get a text field and an `NSString` in its `.h` file:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *myResult; //to contain the result
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITextfield *myResultText; // to display the result
```

In the first View (view1) take inputs and add buttons like (addition +) etc.:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIButton *addition;
```

Connect that Outlet(button) with the view controller. Then add a method for that button and connect it to that button:

```
-(int)addFunc;
```

Then take in user input from 2 text fields that you have already made in the 1st View (`input1TextField` and `input2TextField`):

Inside the `addFunc` write:

```
(int)addFunc{
    int input1,input2,result;
    input1 = self.input1TextField.text;
    input2 = self.input2TextField.text;
    result = input1+input2;
    return result;
}
```

Now inside the `IBaction` method write:

```
-(IBAction)myIbaction{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier @"seguename", sender :self]; // set the segue name and fill it here.
    SecondViewController * sec = [segue destinationViewController];
    int result = [self addFunc];
    sec.myResult = (NSString)result;
}
```

Now in the second View (view2) in `viewDidLoad` method write:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    self.myResultText = self.myResult;
}
```

And it will display your result.
Don't know if it helps or not but surely you get the picture that this is how you will be able to perform it.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Remember to add indentation to the code you're writing so that it's displayed properly. (:

Comment: sorry, i am new to stackoverflow so forgive me if there is any mistake

Comment: No problem! You'll get used to the guidelines and formatting rules as you use it. Just make sure your posts meet the guidelines. (:

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare this method in the second `UIContainerView`:

```
UIContainerView2
-(id)initWithsetresult:(Int)Result {
   int showPreResult = result;
   return self;
}
```

On button action:

```
 antagonist = [[UIContainerView2 alloc]initWithsetresult: calculateResult];
```